# Select only available rows of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Let say I have the following `pandas df`

```
import pandas as pd
d = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0]
e = pd.Series(d, index = ['a', 'b', 'c'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': 1., 'B': e, 'C': pd.Timestamp('20130102')})
```

Now I have another array

```
select = ['c', 'a', 'x']
```

Clearly, the element `'x'` is not available in my original `df`. How can I select rows of `df` based on `select` but choose only available rows without any error? i.e. in this case, I want to select only rows corresponding to `'c'` and `'a'` maintaining this order.

Any pointer will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `reindex` + `dropna`:

```
out = df.reindex(select).dropna()
```

you could also filter select before `reindex`:

```
out = df.reindex([i for i in select if i in df.index])
```

Output:

```
     A    B          C
c  1.0  2.0 2013-01-02
a  1.0  0.0 2013-01-02
```